# Series expansion with fractional exponents

Tags: series-expansion

The following series expansion

```
Series[1 + Sum[b[n] (x^(1/4))^n, {n, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

gives terms up to `O(x^{5/4})`. I would like to only retain terms up to and including `O(x^{1/2})`.  I would like to modify my initial command to the following,

```
Series[1 + Sum[b[n] (x^(1/4))^n, {n, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 1/2}]
```

which does not work since Mathematica is expecting a machine-sized integer. Clearly, Mathematica can perform this fractional expansion, but yet how to only retain fraction terms to a specific order?

Comment: I suggest defining a variable to represent the 4th root of x and expanding wrt that

Comment: The `O` operator can be used explicitly to drop higher terms, although that would not be automatic, as in: `Series[1 + Sum[b[n] (x^(1/4))^n, {n, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 1}] + O[x]^(3/4)` which returns: `1 + b[1] x^(1/4) + b[2] Sqrt[x] + O[x]^(3/4)`

Comment: With that notation you do not need the `Series` at all.  Just `1 + Sum[b[n]*(x^(1/4))^n, {n, 1, 3}] + O[x]^(3/4)`.